# What is the Perl equivalent for PHP's $_FILES for file uploads?

Tags: php, perl, file-upload

What is the Perl equivalent of PHP's `$_FILES`?  I've got some software that sends log files to a web server and I need to retrieve them using Perl instead of PHP.  I'm using CGI.pm.

Here's the code in PHP:

```
<?
    foreach ($_FILES as $key=>$value)
        {
         $uploaded_file = $_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'];
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's in the [pod](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.42/CGI.pm#CREATING_A_FILE_UPLOAD_FIELD):

```
my $q = CGI->new();

# get filehandle like objects from the query. 
my @uploaded_files = $q->upload();

# get file by name
my $fh = $q->upload('uploaded_file');
```

Comment: I actually couldn't get $q->upload to work - I had to explicitly call the name using $q->upload('uploaded_file').  Not sure why.  Have you been able to loop through uploaded files without knowing the name?

Comment: Are you assigning the results in a list context, for example to an array?  my @files = $q->upload(); or  (my $file) = $q->upload();  It's been a long time since I did anything with CGI.pm, and I don't recall if I used the list context version of upload.

Comment: Yeah, using my @files = $q->upload();